# Predictive code completion and custom functions in contexts

Tags: front-end, packages, version-9

Suppose I work for organisation PQR, and have been developing a suite of packages, `PQRUtilities`, `PQRVisualization` etc, all of which are neatly arranged in a context `PQR`. They can all then be loaded with a single package call `` Get["PQR`"] ``.

The only content of the PQR package is

```
BeginPackage["PQR`" ,{"PQR`PQRVisualization`","PQR`PQRUtilities`"}]
(* Exported symbols added here with SymbolName::usage - but nothing here *)    
Begin["`Private`"]
(* Implementation of the package - nothing here either*)  
End[]    
EndPackage[]
```

I have noticed that if I call the subsidiary packages directly with ``` Get["PQR`PQRVisualization``"] ``` or the `Needs` equivalent, I get predictive code completion pop-ups including my custom functions.

However, if I just call `` Get["PQR`"] ``, my functions are loaded but I do not get the nice predictive code completion.

Ultimately all these packages will be put in the `Autoload` part of the path, so maybe this doesn't matter. I would like to be able to provide the simpler way to load all the custom packages I've developed, and still enjoy the benefits of the code-completion suggestions. Some of my function names are quite long, e.g. `PQRScatterGraph`.

Is there a way I can get functions from packages loaded in this way to be visible to the code completion functionality?

Comment: Verbeia wrote: `if I call the subsidiary packages directly with Needs equivalent, I get predictive code completion pop-ups including my custom functions.`  ............................  BUT (a) does the little drop down triangle appear that autocompletes WITH the function arguments??  and (b) if you click on the little HELP button on the RHS (which is meant to open the Help page for that function), does that work?      Because neither (a) nor (b) are working for me for third party packages. I reported this to Wolfram, and got back a reply saying it was a bug re (b). I didn't report issue (a).

Comment: @wolfies I can't answer this as I haven't yet written the function help pages.

Comment: @wolfies - I just checked, and after implementing halirutan's solution, yes, both (a) and (b) work for my custom functions. Well, I get a "file not found" error when I try to open documentation pages that don't exist, but it works other than that :)

Comment: Symbols buried deep in contexts (e.g. ``a`b`c``) don't auto-complete.  I suggested to support that this would be nice to have.  If you also do, maybe they'll implement it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your situation, the *standard approach* is usually different. This means, I use something like this only

```
BeginPackage["PQR`" ,{"PQR`PQRVisualization`","PQR`PQRUtilities`"}]
```

when I need the functionality of the Visualization and Utilities inside my package, not to re-export them.
What about creating an directory structure the following way

```
PQR
├── Kernel
│   └── init.m
├── PQRUtilities.m
└── PQRVisualization.m
```

And in the `init.m` you `Get` your sub-packages. Placing this in folder which *Mathematica* can find lets you `` <<PQR` `` and everything should work as expected.

---

**Update:**
If you want to have an example where such approach is used, then look at `$InstallationDirectory/AddOns/Packages/BarCharts`. You load `` <<BarCharts` ``, but there is no package `BarCharts.m`, it's only a collection of different sub-packages which are loaded through the `init.m`

```
BarCharts/
├── Charts.m
├── Charts3D.m
├── Kernel
│   └── init.m
├── PacletInfo.m
└── Usage.m
```

And the `Kernel/init.m` contains

```
Get["BarCharts`Usage`"];
Get["BarCharts`Charts`"];
Get["BarCharts`Charts3D`"];
```

---

There was a follow-up question from Verbeia in the comments:

> This works great, thanks! But one quick question - is there a reason why it works for Get and gives an error Needs::nocont: Context PQR` was not created when Needs was evaluated. >> when using Needs

Yes, the reason is that `` Needs["PQR`"] `` expects that a context `` PQR` `` is actually created which is not the case if it is really just a dummy directory/package. 
This means,

- when you set up the structure like I described
- and there is no `.m` file which is named after the parent package directory `PQR`
- and every sub-package only creates its own context by calling `` BeginPackage["PQR`Sub`"] ``

then you get this warning when you call `` Needs["PQR`"] ``.

If you inspect now the BarCharts example in more detail, you see that they, although using different file names, always use `` BeginPackage["BarCharts`"] `` and therefore introduce there different functions in the same namespace/context. The question is here, what you want to achieve with your package structure, because after loading your package all exported functions are *visible* without you noticing they are in different sub-packages/contexts.

What I usually do is the following: When my packages contain several sub-packages, then there is still one main-package which provides core functionality. To give an specific example: An image processing package `IP` could provide basic functions under `IP/IP.m` while addressing more special things in sub-packages like `IP/Segmentation.m`. The simplest solution for you is therefore to make a package file `PQR/PQR.m` which introduces the namespace/context `` PQR` `` and the message will be gone.

*Note that if some subpackages use functions that are defined in other subpackages, you will need to order the calls to `Get` in `init.m` carefully.*